# Como criar um bucket na Aws s3 usando android?

Tags: java, android, amazon-aws

Estou tentando fazer dessa forma:

```java
public AmazonS3Client getS3Client(Context context) {
        BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
        s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
        s3Client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_2));

        return s3Client;

    }


public void createBucket() {
        if(amazonS3Client.doesBucketExist(bucketName)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Já existe");
        } else {
            amazonS3Client.createBucket(bucketName);
            Log.i(TAG, "Deu certo.");
        }

    }
```

Mas não tenho certeza se precisa de mais algum parâmetro ou não. Seria essa a forma certa?

Comment: Eu não recomendaria deixar suas credenciais da AWS em um aplicativo Java, o APK pode ser facilmente decompilado e suas credenciais vão ficar expostas. A melhor forma seria chamar um backend de forma segura, e o backend realizar as operações nos buckets.

Answer (score 1):

Verifiquei na documentação que esse método deve ser suficiente para criar, mas existe outros construtores que tu pode passar a região por exemplo.

Link da doc: https://aws-amplify.github.io/aws-sdk-android/docs/reference/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html